# How do I put the URL before the author?

Tags: biblatex, biber, online, url

I have very specific requirements for my bibliography style but can't realize them... I'm using bibTex with an @online-entry and have to put the URL at the beginning of an entry. So it should look for example like this:
http//www.abc.com/xyz.html, Crane, G., About something, visited on 01.02.2018. 
This is my .tex-file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, notitlepage]{article}  
\usepackage[style=authortitle, citestyle=authoryear, giveninits=true, 
uniquename=init, backend=biber]{biblatex}  
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}  
\bibliography{bib.bib}  
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\setunit{\addspace}\printdate}  
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} 
\begin{document}  
\nocite{*}  
\printbibliography[type=online]  
\newpage  
\end{document}
```

and this is bib.bib:

```
@online{test,
author = {Gerhard Crane},
title = {About something},
url = {http://abc.com/xyz.html},
urldate = {2018-02-01},
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Assuming you use BibTeX, do please tell us which bibliography style you employ at present. Since you set the `biber` tag, it's not entirely clear, though whether you use BibTeX or biblatex/biber. Please clarify.

Comment: Please provide code for a minimal document with bibliography which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem. If you are really using `bibtex` (and not just a database of BibTeX entries), then remove the `biber` tag. If you are using Biber, remove the `bibtex` tag and add `biblatex`.

Comment: A solution will not only depend on the package (`biblatex`) you use, but also on the bibliography style you use. Please show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that we can get started more easily and can make sure that the answer works for you. What about the sorting in this case?

Comment: You might also want to explain how you want to cite these entries, again that depends on the citation/bibliography style you use.

Comment: `style=authortitle, citestyle=authoryear` is an interesting and possibly confusing combinations already. But how should citations to `@online` entries look?

Comment: Any news here? Can you explain how you would sort entries and what citations should look like?

Comment: It should look like this: http//www.abc.com/xyz.html, Crane, G., About something, visited on 01.02.2018.

Comment: Even if you use `\cite` you want to see the entire entry and not just, say 'Crane 2018'  as with the other entries? We are still none the wiser about the sorting in the bibliography.

Comment: I don't use \cite but \footfullcite (so I could delete citestyle=authoryear). So the footnote and the entry in the bibliography should look like my example above.

Comment: What about sorting?

Comment: How would that look like?

Comment: I'm asking you about the sorting in the bibliography. With the `authortitle` style the entries in the bibliography are sorted by author name and then title. That makes sense because these two are the first thing you see in an entry. But now suppose the URL is the first bit of an entry. Would all online sources still be sorted under author and title (which are much less prominent now) or should they be sorted using their URL meaning they are all sorted under 'h'?

Answer (score 1):

We change the field formats for `url` and `urldate` a bit and move the URL to the start with `begentry`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, notitlepage]{article}  
\usepackage[style=authortitle, citestyle=authoryear, giveninits=true, 
uniquename=init, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{test,
author = {Gerhard Crane},
title = {About something},
url = {http://abc.com/xyz.html},
urldate = {2018-02-01},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\setunit{\addspace}\printdate}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\ifentrytype{online}{\usebibmacro{url}\clearfield{url}\newunit\newblock}{}}

\begin{document}  
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=online]
\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]